Помогите, вывести на кнопку Да, текстовое сообщение, перепробывал все что можно и нельзя ничего не получается
import telebot

from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('6313714090:AAHha-hyp9s9aP7GXAofQUOwLifnXYBZXes')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    iten = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Да', callback_data='question_1')
    markup.add(iten)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'{message.from_user.first_name} Совершенно любой текст тут можно написать похожий по объему') and bot.send_message(message.chat.id,text= 'Тут тоже самое очень похож по объему', reply_markup = markup)

   




bot.infinity_polling()


Вам нужно создать обработчик который будет реагировать на callback
Пример который должен сработать в вашем случае:
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'question_1')
def handle_question_1(call):
    bot.answer_callback_query(call.id)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Вы выбрали "Да"!')

